# TListItem Objects

Tags: delphi, vcl, listitem

I would like to program the following situation:

I have 2 different ListViews in a form. I would like to attach specific items from ListView2 into a ListView1 item. After the "Parent" Item gets deleted, it should also delete all the attached items from ListView2.
I tried this so far:

```
type
 TITEMS = record
 A_Items : array of TListItem;
end;
```

A Button that adds an item to ListView1 (ParentItems)

```
var
 item : TListItem;
begin
 item := ListView1.Items.Add;
 item.Caption := 'ParentTestItem';
 item.SubItems.Add('TestSubItem');
```

A button that adds an item to ListView2 (ChildItems)

```
 var
  item : TlistItem;
  items : TITEMS;
 begin
  if ListView1.Selected = NIL then exit; // Make sure an item is selected.
  item := ListView2.Items.Add;
  item.Caption := 'ChildTestItem';
  item.SubItems.Add('TestSubItem');
  SetLength (items.item, Length(items.item) + 1); // wrong? 
  items.item[Length(items.item)-1] := item;
  ListView1.Selected.SubItems.Objects[0] := @items;
```

A button that removes a ParentItem (and it should delete ChildItems as well...)

```
  var
   items : TItems;
   i : Integer;
   item : TlistItem;
  begin
   if ListView1.Selected = NIL then exit; // Make sure an item is selected.
   items := TItems(ListView1.Selected.SubItems.Objects[0]); // Cast
   for i := 0 to Length (items.item) - 1 do begin
    item := items.item[i];
    item.Delete;
   end;
   ListView1.Selected.Free;
```

Any Idea how I could realize this?

Comment: Stack allocated `TITEMS` can't work. As soon as the function returns, poof, that variable has gone. So you'd need to put them on the heap. But getting the list view to own this seems like a bad idea. You want a virtual list view.

Comment: any idea how I could do it without virtual listview?

Comment: Well, I'd be using TListItem.Data as my storage. And you need a heap allocated thing. Probably an instance of a class. But it sucks really hard that way. Why don't you do it properly with virtual paradigm. You'll never look back. Is the list view really your primary data structure?!

Comment: it is. I have only those 2 ListViews. I know it's possible to attach one childitem to a parentitem. but more than one needs something like an array.

Comment: Use ListItem.Data and store a class instance in there. You'll need to manage the lifetime carefully. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it with ListItem.Data.

Comment: The sooner you ditch TListView and go to a proper control, like Virtual TreeView, the better. http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview  -- doing without such a nice control just so you can use TListView and data-pointers, is wrong-headed.

Comment: @Warren TListView works well in virtual mode. No need to ditch TListView to get virtual paradigm.

Comment: Is there a sample app of that somewhere?  Note that even in virtual mode, its appearance doesnt improve and its features are a paltry subset of the capabilities of Virtual TreeView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate the list of items dynamically on the heap, not locally on the stack, so it stays valid in memory while you are using it.

I would suggest using a `TList` instead of an array, it is easier to allocate dynmically.  I would also suggest using the `TListItem.Data` property instead of the `TListItem.SubItems.Objects[]` property (unless you are already using the `Data` property for something else).

```
procedure TForm1.AddParentBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  item : TListItem; 
begin 
  item := ListView1.Items.Add; 
  item.Caption := 'ParentTestItem'; 
  item.SubItems.Add('TestSubItem'); 
end;

procedure TForm1.AddChildBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  Selected, item : TListItem; 
  items : TList; 
begin 
  Selected := ListView1.Selected;
  if Selected = nil then Exit; // Make sure an item is selected. 

  items := TList(Selected.Data);
  if items = nil then begin
    items := TList.Create;
    Selected.Data := items;
  end;

  item := ListView2.Items.Add; 
  try
    item.Caption := 'ChildTestItem'; 
    item.SubItems.Add('TestSubItem'); 
    items.Add(item); 
  except
    item.Delete;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DeleteParentBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Selected : TListItem; 
begin
  Selected := ListView1.Selected;
  if Selected <> nil then Selected.Delete;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
var 
  items : TList; 
  i : Integer; 
begin 
  items := TList(Item.Data); // Cast 
  if items <> nil then begin
    for i := 0 to items.Count - 1 do begin 
     TListItem(items[i]).Delete; 
    end; 
    items.Free;
    Item.Data := nil;
  end;
end;
```